# Selected values in custom control disappear on postback

Tags: asp.net, postback, page-lifecycle

I have a asp.NET web forms page with nested datalists.  The inner datalist contains a custom control which contains a dropdownlist.  The custom control is declared in page markup. All controls have ViewsState enabled.

All data binding events have

```
if (!Page.IsPostback)
```

surrounding statements.

When the outer datalist fires it's OnDataBound event, I load the inner datalist.

Similarly, when the inner datalist fires it's OnDataBound event, I load the customcontrol.

Everything in the custom control is binding to actual data correctly on load, but when I try to SAVE changes, the selected values of the drop down lists in the user controls have vanished.  (That is, when I post back with a SAVE method, I inspect the drop down lists : they exist, but they are not bound.)

How to a prevent changed values from being unbound before I can SAVE?

Comment: You are likely loading the lists in your PageLoad event without first checking if you are in postback.  If you are in postback, don't repopulate the data.

Comment: I have *if (!Page.IsPostback)* around the Page_Load and both databinding events ... with no improvement.

Comment: By 'I load the control' are you dynamically adding the custom control to the datalist or does it exist in the page markup?

Comment: The custom control exists in page markup....